# Uploading a video in S3 Using Future

Tags: multithreading, scala, amazon-s3

I've posted a similar program previously, but I have not made any major modifications in the code, so I am posting it again by deleting the previous question.

**I am afraid of the thread keyword** and I am not too familiar with threads and blocking, so can you please review this code for me?

**Is the use of future enough or not?**

This code comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449967/exception-caught-in-requestbodyhandler).

**Note**: The AWS credentials are fake.

```
package controllers

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.util.ArrayList

import scala.collection.JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap
import scala.concurrent.Future

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair

import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException

import net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
import net.liftweb.json.Serialization.write
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.i18n.Lang
import play.api.i18n.Messages
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
import play.api.mvc.Action
import play.api.mvc.Controller

object Application extends Controller {

  val bucketImages = "images35"
  val bucketVideos = "videos35"
  val bucketAudios = "audios35"

  val AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq"
  val AWS_SECRET_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

  val yourAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)
  val amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(yourAWSCredentials)

  val ACCOUNT_SID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  val AUTH_TOKEN = "tytytytytyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"

  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

 def uploadVideo = Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
session.get("userI").map { userId =>
  try {
    var videoName: String = null
    val upload = for {
      done <- Future {
    request.body.files.map { mov =>
      videoName =System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mpeg"
      amazonS3Client.putObject(bucketVideos, videoName, mov.ref.file)
      }
      }
    } yield done
    upload.map { res =>
      val map = Map("result" -> "success", "videoName" -> videoName)
      Ok(write(map))
    }
  } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      Future{
      Ok(write(Map("result" -> "error")))
      }
  }
}.getOrElse {
  Future{
  Ok(write(Map("result" -> "nosession")))
   }
  }
 }
}
```

**application.conf**

```
play {
  akka {
    event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
    loglevel = WARNING
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-min = 300
          parallelism-max = 300
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
contexts {
  simple-db-lookups {
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-factor = 10.0
    }
  }
  expensive-db-lookups {
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-max = 4
    }
  }
  db-write-operations {
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-factor = 2.0
    }
  }
  expensive-cpu-operations {
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-max = 2
    }
  }
}
```

**Contexts Object**

```
object Contexts {
  implicit val simpleDbLookups: ExecutionContext = Akka.system.dispatchers.lookup("contexts.simple-db-lookups")
  implicit val expensiveDbLookups: ExecutionContext = Akka.system.dispatchers.lookup("contexts.expensive-db-lookups")
  implicit val dbWriteOperations: ExecutionContext = Akka.system.dispatchers.lookup("contexts.db-write-operations")
  implicit val expensiveCpuOperations: ExecutionContext = Akka.system.dispatchers.lookup("contexts.expensive-cpu-operations")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, remove `import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._`. You don't want the default Play execution context. Instead, you should use one of the `ExecutionContext`s you've defined and aren't using. Perhaps define one for S3 operations alone, and you don't need the others if you aren't going to use them. `Future.apply` requires the implicit `ExecutionContext`, so you can either import the correct one, or explicitly pass it.

Assuming you have a context defined like this in your configuration:

```
contexts {
    s3-ops {
        fork-join-executor {
            parallelism-factor = 10.0
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your controller you could add:

```
implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = Akka.system.dispatchers.lookup("contexts.s3-ops")
```

Now in the body of the controller function, I'll work my way inward. With the handling of the `session`, why bother returning data to the user if they don't have a session? It would seem more appropriate to return `Forbidden`, which can shorten that line to `Future.successful(Forbidden)`. Note that `Future.successful` creates a `Future` that has already been completed.

The use of try/catch is not very Scala-like. There are other nicer ways to handle errors in Scala like [Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Try). `Future` is actually very similar to `Try`, though, and it should provide all the error handling you need in this case. If an exception occurs within a `Future`, then it becomes a failed `Future`. No exceptions will propagate upward. Most of the code inside your `try` block can go inside the `Future` apply instead.

`var videoName: String = null` is something that should be avoided altogether. First, it's best to avoid mutable `var`s, and second you should **never** find yourself assigning `null` to anything.

I'm not sure the body of your current `Future` where you're mapping `request.body.files` is doing what you think it's doing. `request.body.files` is a `Seq[FilePart]`, which means if there are multiple `FilePart`s, you're going to upload them all separately, overwrite `videoName` and only return the name of the last uploaded `FilePart`. Or worse, if there are no `FilePart`s, that part will silently fail. If you're only going to have a single `FilePart`, it'd be better to name it in the upload body and access via `request.body.file("filename")` which will be an `Option[FilePart]`. From there you can `map` the `Option[FilePart]` to the actual upload.

Since you're not actually doing anything with the `PutObjectResult` from the S3 response, it'd be better to return the name of the file in the `Future`, so that you have access to it when you `map` the `Future`, and would no longer have a need for a `var`. Following the suggestions above, it would now be a `Future[Option[String]]`.

This would leave you with three return states for the `Future`:

1. A successful `Future` containing `Some[String]` (upload success on both ends).
2. A successful `Future` containing `None` (no file was uploaded to the server).
3. A failed `Future` (the upload to S3 failed somehow).

You'd then have something that looks roughly like this:

```
Future {
    request.body.file("filename").map{ file =>
        val videoName = ...
        amazonS3Client.putObject(...)
        videoName
    }
}.map{ upload =>
    upload.map{videoName => Ok(...)}.getOrElse{BadRequest(...)}
}.recover{ case _ =>  // recover the failed `Future` to a default value, in this case a `Result`
    InternalServerError
}
```

Much cleaner. Note that `recover` accepts a `PartialFunction[Throwable, ?]`, similarly to a `catch` block, so you can be more fine grained in your error handling if you need to.

A couple more notes:

There's no need to use Lift's json API for your responses. [Play's implementation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson) works just fine:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
Ok(Json.obj("result" -> "success", "videoName" -> videoName))
```

Your imports take up **a lot** of space. Many can be condensed into one liners:

```
 import play.api.i18n.Lang
 import play.api.i18n.Messages
```

Can be:

```
 import play.api.i18n.{Lang, Messages}
```